# Jquery not getting the correct screen size

Tags: jquery, css

I don't know exactly where the problem comes from, so I did a guess in the title.

Basically, what I am trying to do is

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="content">Content</div><!-- Max screen height possible -->
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

After doing a simple calculation such as: `window_height - header_height - footer_height`, it is not fitting correctly in the screen. (total 3 divs height is bigger than the window)

```
function adjustbody(){
    var windowh = $(window).height();
    var headerh = $("#header").height();
    var footerh = $("#footer").height();
    var contenth = windowh - headerh - footerh;
    $("#content").css("min-height",contenth);
}
```

See full code here. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wm3pw/1/)

Am I missing some height to substract?

Comment: Use `screen.height` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset your body/html margin and padding.

```
body, html {

    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

}
```

Comment: The problem wasn't exactly in the `body` margin / padding (in the big project), but it was because of the padding, which you gave me the idea to check. You were also the first one to answer, so. Accepted

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the code.

The problem in your fiddle is that body has a default margin. Remove that and it works fine.